# How to know how much of the same structure i have to parse

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to parse this using ANTLR4 :

```
FSM
name type String
state type State
Relation
name type String
Mathieu
name type String
```

Someone helped me, corrected my grammar and i got this thanks to him

```
grammar Generator;

parse
 : classToGenerate+ EOF;

classToGenerate
 : name=Name attributes+;

attributes
 : attribute=Name 'type' type=Name;

Name   : [a-zA-Z]+;
Spaces : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

I am using the parser generated by ANTLR4 this way :

```
   GeneratorLexer l = new GeneratorLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(GeneratorFactory.class.getResourceAsStream("/example.generator")));
GeneratorParser p = new GeneratorParser(new CommonTokenStream(l)); 
p.addParseListener(new GeneratorBaseListener() {
           @Override public void exitClassToGenerate(GeneratorParser.ClassToGenerateContext ctx) {
              System.out.println(ctx.name.getText());
           }

           @Override
           public void exitAttributes(GeneratorParser.AttributesContext ctx) {
               System.out.println(ctx.type.getText());
               System.out.println(ctx.attribute.getText());
           }
       });
```

Here is the result after executing

```
String
name
State
state
FSM
```

Where is the rest ? 
It didn't print Relation name String // Mathieu name String

Any idea ?

EDIT : Okay it seems i was able to print the rest of the files but i've still have something to figure out.
When i do :

```
p.classToGenerate();
```

It parses the first structure which results in the print i had.
If i want to find another structure i need to do another

```
p.classToGenerate();
```

The thing is, how should i know how much structure i have to parse?
Imagine i have 5 or 20 same structures, how can i know it ?

Thanks !

Comment: When I run your grammar and input with grun, I get back a tree containing three `classToGenerate` nodes, which I assume is what you want. So it looks like whatever issue you're having comes from somewhere else.

Comment: Just to know, how did you check on grun ?
I used the command "grun Generator example -gui", it stucks in the terminal showing nothing

Comment: I used `grun Generator parse -gui` (there is no rule named `example` in the grammar you posted). You'll need to enter the input into the terminal and then close the stream (Ctrl+d on Unixoid systems or Ctrl+z on Windows) before anything happens. You can also save the input in a file and then run `grun Generator parse inputfile.txt -gui`.

Comment: Oh thank you ! i missed the rule in my command (sorry i am really new to antlr4)
I still have to figure out why it's not working the way i want but thanks

Comment: I've added code to my question, if you want to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your grammar you've called your main rule `parse`. The rule `classToGenerate` only matches a single class. So in order to match all classes in the file, you should call `p.parse();`, not `p.classToGenerate();`.

Comment: Thank you, it was exacty that... (i feel stupid ahah)